# Not able to see the Linux kernel debug info after building kernel in debug mode

Tags: kernel, debugging

I tried to build Linux Kernel versions 3.10.107 and 4.13.8 in debug mode.
I have used following steps to build the kernel.

Host machine with Ubuntu 16.04 OS and trying to update its kernel to latest version(4.13.8) with debug info.

## Get the latest kernel source code

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.13.8.tar.xz
mkdir linux-4.13.8 && tar xvf linux-4.13.8.tar.xz -C $(pwd)/linux-4.13.8/
cd linux-4.13.8
```

## Copy .config from the host linux

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config
```

## Below options are enabled to build kernel in debug mode

```
gedit .config
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
```

## Verified a gui menu of menuconfig

```
make menuconfig
```

Inside the Kernel hacking option, (kernel debugging, compile the kernel debug info, Printk options)  are enabled  and default debug message and console level is 7.

## Executed the make command. kernel builds successfully.

make -j4

## Installing the kernel

```
sudo make modules_install install
```

## Updated the Grub2

```
sudo update-grub2
```

## Reboot the OS

```
reboot
```

OS updated with the latest Kernel 4.13.8 and works well, but debug info and printk outputs are not seen in dmesg console output and log files like(var/log/kern.log, dmesg, syslog)

I have also tried to debug the kernel image with gdb and it show (no debugging symbols found)

Please help to debug kernel. My intention is to debug and analyse system calls,traps, user space to kernel space switching, memory management in detail.
(Expected more debug information than with strace output)

Comment: Please show us the exact steps you followed. As a short starting point, maybe this will help : https://www.elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb

Comment: Did you remember to add `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL`?